# Work out the days between appointments

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a table, Appointments which holds the following information

Name, Date, Type (of Appointment)

I want to work out the difference in days between appointments for each Name.  Some Names may have only 1 appointment, others may have 50.  What I'd like is the average number of days between each appointment.

I've tried inner join, creating a temporary table and using no end of answers on StackOverflow but none seem to work.

My latest version is :

```
    SELECT A.Name, A.Date, (B.Date - A.Date) AS timedifference
FROM Appointments A CROSS JOIN Appointments B
WHERE B.Name IN (SELECT MIN(C.Date) FROM Appointments C WHERE C.Date > A.Date)
ORDER BY A.Name ASC
```

But that times out my webpage.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Claire

Comment: So date is UNIXTIME ??

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Date is DATE format in mysql and, I'm really sorry but I don't know how to do DDLs and/or sqlfiddle.

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve:

John Smith 1/3/2014 Haircut
John Smith 18/3/2014 BeardTrim
John Smith 6/4/2014 Haircut
Number of days between appointments 1 & 2 17 days, between 2 & 3 19 days, Average between all appointments 18 days

Comment: Take a look at my answer it should be what you were looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sub query that calculates the UNIX_TIMESTAMP difference between dates
and then convert from seconds to days by `name`.

```
SELECT (SELECT ( Unix_timestamp() - Sum(Unix_timestamp(`date`)) / Count(*) ) / 
               60 / 60 / 24 
        FROM   `appointments` 
        WHERE  `name` = `ap`.`name` 
        GROUP  BY `name`) AS `daydiff`, 
       `ap`.`name` 
FROM   `appointments` `ap` 
GROUP  BY `name`
```

Take a look at this SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85c19/7

Comment: Thanks @Dan Revah - this is a really stupid question but how do I get the result to show in php?
Sorry to ask

Comment: Same as you run your other custom queries. creating a connection to the server, running the query and fetching results. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: @Claire also if this answer helped you. you should accept it as the right answer clicking the V icon near the top left corner of the answer.

Comment: Have done and 'duh' missed the AS `daydiff` in the code.  Thank you so much for your help have been struggling with this for days.